# Showing Balloon Error Message in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

The below validation is working fine. Can you please help me to show the balloon which should have the error message at right corner of corresponding textbox.

```
<input id="txtLow" class="txtCell" ng-model='data.low' ng-class="{ redBorder: isMinMaxInvalid() }">
<input id="txtHigh" class="txtCell" ng-model='data.high' ng-class="{ redBorder: isMinMaxInvalid() }">
<button id="btnSave"  ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
```

In controller,

```
$scope.saveData = function() {
        if (!$scope.isInvalid()) {
            .........
        }
    };
$scope.isInvalid = function () {
        return $scope.data.low > $scope.data.high;
    };
```

Comment: if you are using bootstrap go for http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips else you can try http://www.brentmckendrick.com/code/xtform/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you Angular-ui/bootstrap which models bootstrap components as AngularJS directives. So you dont have to create them by yourself

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

Only drawback can be that this library currently has some bugs when using with Angular 1.3.

But most funkcionality including tooltips work. I have tested tooltip in 1.3.5 and it looks good.